# Using PHP Class Structures to Generate JSON Documents

Tags: php, json, class

Is anyone able to give me an insight how to use PHP classes to generate a JSON structure based on the following template

```
{
"Summary": "A long route",
published": true,
"Route 1": [
    {
        "Lat": 23.4,
        "Long": 34.5
    },
    {
        "Lat": 27.4,
        "Long": 384.5
    } ...
]
"Route 2": [
    {
        "Lat": 25.4,
        "Long": 34.5
    },
    {
        "Lat": 29.4,
        "Long": 384.5
    } ...
]......
```

}

I am able to generate a constructor function that allows me to instantiate the classes  using the method of `$routes['Route 1'] = new Route[32.4,34.5]` but I am not sure how to generate additional waypoints, or Lat and Long elements for a say `Route 1`, without re-instantiating the Route class.

Comment: You could create methods in your class like `addWaypoint()` and `removeWaypoint()`?

Comment: You are using `json_encode()` to build a json string arn't you. You are not trying to build the string manually in a text string are you

Comment: Yes, I didn't state that but it is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class which will take care of your json:

```
<?php
Class Routes {

    private $routes = [];

    public function __construct($summary, $published){
        $this->routes['summary'] = $summary;
        $this->routes['published'] = $published;
    }

    public function addRoute($route){
        $this->routes[$route] = [];     
    }

    public function addWaypoint($route, $lat, $lon){
        $this->routes[$route][] = [
            "lat" => $lat,
            "long" => $lon
        ];
    }

    public function createJson(){
        return json_encode($this->routes);
    }

}

$routes = new Routes("A long route", true);
$routes->addRoute("Route 1");
$routes->addRoute("Route 2");
$routes->addWaypoint("Route 1", 23.4, 34.5);
$routes->addWaypoint("Route 1", 27.4, 384.5);
$routes->addWaypoint("Route 2", 25.4, 34.5);
$routes->addWaypoint("Route 2", 29.4, 384.5);

echo $routes->createJson();
```

Returns this JSON:

```
{  
   "summary":"A long route",
   "published":true,
   "Route 1":[  
      {  
         "lat":23.4,
         "long":34.5
      },
      {  
         "lat":27.4,
         "long":384.5
      }
   ],
   "Route 2":[  
      {  
         "lat":25.4,
         "long":34.5
      },
      {  
         "lat":29.4,
         "long":384.5
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daan.  That is exactly what I was after.  I thought I was close to getting the answer with my efforts but after seeing yours I realised that I had a way to go.   I tried to vote you up, but I have such a meagre reputation it has no effect.:-(   Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without needing to create a formal class, but by simply using `stdClass()`

```
<?php

$json = new stdClass();
$json->summary = "A long route";
$json->published = true;

$routes = array();
$routes[] = array('Lat' => 23.4, 'Long' => 34.5);
$routes[] = array('Lat' => 27.4, 'Long' => 384.5);

$json->Route1 = $routes;

$routes = array();
$routes[] = array('Lat' => 11.4, 'Long' => 12.5);
$routes[] = array('Lat' => 12.4, 'Long' => 16.5);

$json->Route2 = $routes;

echo json_encode($json);
```

Output :

```
{
 "summary":"A long route",
 "published":true,
 "Route1":[{"Lat":23.4,"Long":34.5},
           {"Lat":27.4,"Long":384.5}
          ],
 "Route2":[{"Lat":11.4,"Long":12.5},
           {"Lat":12.4,"Long":16.5}
          ]
}
```

Comment: Very clever.   You have convinced me to give up on trying to do it with class struction.  Thanks